# Can I use a Time Capsule to share internet connection?

Tags: wifi, hardware, time-capsule

My internet provider limits the number of connected devices to two. I would like to know whether I can use a Time Capsule to share my signal with all other devices in my house?

Comment: How many ports are on your modem? Having worked for and with ISP's in Australia for over 10 years, I have found from experience ISP's try to limit the number of connected hardware through the ethernet ports. How are they able to limit it to 2 devices? If it is not part of your T&C's, then you should be able to create a Wi-Fi connection with your Time Capsule by connecting the WAN port on the Time Capsule to an ethernet port on the modem and use AirPort Utility to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use either the Ethernet ports or WiFi (or both) to allow a Time Capsule to act as a router and share out your connection. Your ISP will, if you set it up in the default manner, have no way of knowing how many devices you have connected using the Time Capsule.

Internally a Time Capsule is actually an AirPort Base Station with a hard drive attached so it makes a great router and WiFi base station. Just connect the Time Capsule to your modem/router using the WAN port on the Time Capsule.